# django form name labels

Tags: django

I am creating a form that creates the form dynamically using my forms.py file in my django app.

Here is my code..

forms.py

```
class TestCriteriaForm(forms.Form):

    testname = forms.CharField()
    serviceoffering = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ServiceOffering.objects.all()) 
    templatename = forms.CharField(help_text="Enter the template name" )
    zone = forms.CharField()
```

template code

```
<form action="/testplatform/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

My problem is that the field names aren't formatted to my liking. Rather than testname, I would like to see 'Test name', or 'Service Offering'

How can I do this without defining more html code than I have to in the template?

Many thanks - Oli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `label` option.

Look at the docs next time.

Comment: HI Marcin.. sorry I was looking at the documentation and just couldn't find what I was looking for.. but you pointed me in the right direction. I;ve added the label to my forms.py as follows --

    testname = forms.CharField(label='Test Name')